# Jquery prop function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to enable/disable some hidden fields based on some calculation and using jquery 
`prop` function, here is the code

```
function enableSelectedFieldsData(count, mapKey, index) {
    $("#code_" + mapKey + "_" + index).prop("disabled", false);
    $("#description_" + mapKey + "_" + index).prop("disabled", false);
    $("#crossRefrence_" + mapKey + "_" + index).prop("disabled", false);
    $("#image_" + mapKey + "_" + index).prop("disabled", false);
    $("#price_" + mapKey + "_" + index).prop("disabled", false);
    // disable all other fields
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            $("#code_" + mapKey + "_" + i).prop("disabled", true);
            $("#description_" + mapKey + "_" + i).prop("disabled", true);
            $("#crossRefrence_" + mapKey + "_" + i).prop("disabled", true);
            $("#image_" + mapKey + "_" + i).prop("disabled", true);
            $("#price_" + mapKey + "_" + i).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Initially i am setting disable=true for all fields and based on the selection i m trying to enable selected fields while disabling other fields, since as per my knowledge disable fields never got submitted to the server on submitting the form, but in my case they are getting submitted.

on checking using firebug i saw that the disable field value for non selected item is getting set as `""` like `disable=""`

i am not sure where i am setting things wrong, any help or pointer in this regard will really be helpful.

**Edit**

I have taken out the relevant section from my generated HTML and placed it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDKRV/5/)
please have a look

Comment: Make sure you're generating the proper selector by those variable.

Comment: @Vins can you describe what exactly you mean by proper selector?

Comment: `$("#crossRefrence_" + mapKey + "_" + index)` In this statement you're using two variable I want you to log those and in console of your browser check whether its selecting proper element. try like this `console.log($("#crossRefrence_" + mapKey + "_" + index))`you should be able to see the matched element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Do you have prop() available?

`prop()` was added in **jQuery 1.6** and is used like this:

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

If you are using **jQuery 1.5.x** or lower you can use `attr()` instead as seen in this [**FAQ - How to enable/disable form elements**](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F) from the jQuery site:

```
// Disable #x
$('#x').attr('disabled', true);

// Enable #x
$('#x').attr('disabled', false);

// -- or --

// Disable #x
$("#x").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

// Enable #x
$("#x").removeAttr('disabled');
```

#### Assuming you are using jQuery 1.6 or higher

Your syntax looks fine. 
I would guess your problem is then most likely incorrect selectors.

To validate the selector contains the element reference you expect do:

```
 // output the selector to the console
console.log($("#code_" + mapKey + "_" + index));
```

If you see an element in your browser's debugging console you are looking at a valid selector, if instead you see `[]` the your selector is invalid.

Alternatively you can check it using the `length` property and alert that out:

```
// alert out the length of the jQuery selector
alert($("#code_" + mapKey + "_" + index).length);
```

If you see `0` then your selector is invalid, if you see `1` or more then your selector is correct.

Comment: i tried it and it giving correct values on console and even with alter giving value as 1, i am not sure whats going wrong here.i saw my page source and Jquery 1.7.0 is being used

Comment: Would it be possible for you to take the relevant code and place it inot a fiddle on jsFiddle? that would allow us to use it as a sandbox to change and debug possible solutions.

Comment: i am using some kind of tags (spring one), so is it possible to just go generated HTML?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi You can see the generated HTML source in Firebug after the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The `disabled` attribute in HTML is a bit different to (most) other attributes, in that its presence alone is enough to disable the element.

```
<input type="text" name="test" disabled>
<input type="text" name="test" disabled="">
<input type="text" name="test" disabled="true">
<input type="text" name="test" disabled="false">
```

Those elements will all be disabled (yes, even the one with `disabled="false"`) because the disabled attribute is present in the HTML. If you're seeing `disabled=""` in Firebug's HTML tab after calling

```
.prop('disabled', true);
```

then that's the correct behaviour, and the element **is** disabled. There's another reason why the values are still being submitted, despite being disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I found that .prop("disabled", true/false) is only working on input element types (i.e. button, checkbox ect.) I was trying to call this on an anchor tag  and it was not working. What I ended up doing was using .attr("disabled", true) and .removeAttr("disabled") to toggle the disabled attribute as it works on all html elements.